# how create a webservice with a database connection?

Tags: android, database, web-services

I want create a android application and i need to connect to a webservice and this web service should have connection to a database.

How is the simple way and free to implement this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a PHP server which is (managing a database and) handling HTML POST requests? You could use [JSON](http://www.json.org/) as communication format. On client side you could even use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to hide the JSON handling.